# Object is weight painted in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, weight-painting

When I go to edit mode my object is weight painted. It did have a armature, but I deleted it. How do I delete the weight painting. I can't apply my modifiers either, because of some shape keys.
Please help!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After deleting the *Armature* modifier go to the *Mesh Data* header and delete all *vertex groups* (click the *black down arrow*-->*Delete All Groups*) in *Vertex Groups* panel. Do the same with *shape keys* in the *Shape Keys* panel to be able to apply your modifiers.
[image]